# Problems Error Checking Code

Tags: java, error-handling, exception, error-checking

```
import java.util.*;

public class AccountClient {

public static void main(String[] args)  {
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean infiniteLoop = true;
    boolean invalidInput;
    int id = 0;

    // Create array of different accounts
    Account[] accountArray = new Account[1000000];
    //Initialize each account array with its own unique id and a starting account balance of $100
    for (int i = 0; i < accountArray.length; i++) {
        accountArray[i] = new Account("name", i, 100);
    }
    do {    
        try {       
            //inner loop to detect invalid Input
            do {
                invalidInput = false;
                System.out.print("Enter an id: ");

                if (!(input.hasNextInt())) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid input. Please enter a numeric id between 0 and 999999, no letters or symbols allowed. Try again.");
                    invalidInput = true;
                    input.nextLine();
                }


                else {
                    id = input.nextInt(); 
                    accountArray[id].setNumberOfTimesOpened(accountArray[id].getNumberOfTimesOpened() + 1);
                    input.nextLine();
                    if (accountArray[id].firstTimeAccount()) {
                        System.out.print("Please enter a name to register to this account: ");
                        String name = input.nextLine();
                        accountArray[id].setName(name);
                    }
                }

            } while (invalidInput);
            boolean exit;
            do {
                exit = false;
                boolean notAnOption;
                int choice;
                do {
                    notAnOption = false;
                    System.out.print("\nMain Menu\n1: check balance\n2: withdraw\n3: deposit\n4: view transaction history\n5: exit\nEnter a choice: ");
                    choice = input.nextInt();
                    if (choice < 1 || choice > 5) {
                        System.out.println("Sorry, " + choice + " is not an option. Please try again and enter a number between 1 and 5 (inclusive).");
                        notAnOption = true;
                    }
                } while(notAnOption);
                switch (choice) {
                case 1: System.out.printf("The balance for your account is $%.2f\n", accountArray[id].getBalance());
                    break;
                case 2: {
                    boolean withdrawFlag;
                    do {
                        System.out.print("Enter the amount you would like to withdraw: ");
                        double withdrawAmount = input.nextDouble();
                        input.nextLine();
                        if (withdrawAmount > accountArray[id].getBalance()) {     
                            System.out.printf("Sorry, you only have an account balance of $%.2f. Please try again and enter a number at or below this amount.\n", accountArray[id].getBalance());
                            withdrawFlag = true;
                        }
                        else {
                            accountArray[id].withdraw(withdrawAmount);
                            System.out.printf("Thank you. You have successfully withdrawn $%.2f from your account.\n", withdrawAmount);
                            withdrawFlag = false;
                        }
                    } while (withdrawFlag);
                }

                    break;
                case 3: {
                    System.out.print("Enter the amount you would like to deposit: ");
                    double depositAmount = input.nextDouble();
                    input.nextLine();
                    accountArray[id].deposit(depositAmount);
                    System.out.printf("Thank you. You have successfully deposited $%.2f into your account.\n", depositAmount); 
                    }
                    break;
                case 4: {
                    accountArray[id].accountSummary();
                    }
                    break;
                case 5: {
                    System.out.println("returning to the login screen...\n");
                    exit = true;
                    }
                    break;
                }

            } while (exit == false);

        }

        catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex1) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input. Please enter an id between 0 and 999999 (inclusive).");  
            input.nextLine();
        }

        catch (InputMismatchException ex2) {
            System.out.println("Sorry, invalid input. Please enter an id between 0 and 999999 (inclusive) with no letters or symbols.");
            input.nextLine();
        }

    } while (infiniteLoop);

  } 

}
```

Hello everyone, I have a program that simulates an ATM machine. It uses the account class which I created to generate an account for a user after they enter an id between 0 and 999999. They can then perform various tasks like view balance, withdraw, deposit, etc. I'm having an issue though with error checking the program. It compiles with no errors and the first time it goes through the loop, it works perfectly. However, if they hit exit and enter another invalid id, It displays the invalid input message twice. I copied the console of what happens below. Can somebody please explain to me why it does this and how to fix it. Also I'm new to java so if anybody can tell me a better way to error check this it would be much appreciated. As of right now if they enter an int value and it isn't in the range of 0 to 999999, I have to have a separate ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException to catch the error. This seems inefficient. Is there a way I can error check if they entered a numeric value and if they did, check again if they entered an input between 0 and 999999? Thanks

Enter an id: f

Invalid input. Please enter a numeric id between 0 and 999999, no letters or symbols allowed. Try again.

Enter an id: 5

Please enter a name to register to this account: Bob

Main Menu

1: check balance

2: withdraw

3: deposit

4: view transaction history

5: exit

Enter a choice: 5

returning to the login screen...

Enter an id: f

Invalid input. Please enter a numeric id between 0 and 999999, no letters or symbols allowed. Try again.

Enter an id: Invalid input. Please enter a numeric id between 0 and 999999, no letters or symbols allowed. Try again.

Enter an id:

Answer (score 0):

I got zero help from anyone but after hours of frustration I realized this was because I failed to put input.nextLine() after I asked the user to pick a choice. This caused the scanner not to be cleared and caused the statement to be printed twice before it got cleared in the inner loop I had at the start. Once i added the input.nextLine() it worked fine.